# woocommerce with external ftp site

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, uploads, hosting, ftp

i am  creating a site with wplms theme use woocommerce for selling part.

i am trying to use another host for files(host run minimal php that use x-accel-redirect functions)

and i want to limit download access to authorized user and i use wordpress plugin upload-to-ftp for uploading the file and Secure Downloads for limiting access

but because they are not in same host it does't work.

if anyone know a better way please tell me.

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

fortunately ftp server had install nginx and i used x-accel-redirect inside downlod server to solve my problem.

thanks for your helps:)